# sed print Nth character

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed

I have a list of strings that are always 5 characters long. What is the best way to transform the first, third and fifth character (including space) of each line into individual strings?

Input:

```
c   c
8   8
4   4
3   3
1   1
4   4
9   9
8 | c
  > 4
0   0
e | 5
6 | a
3   3
9 | c
b <  
1   1
b | 0
d <  
4   4
5 | 7
c   c
  > 3
.   .
1 | c
o   o
```

Output:

```
c8431498 0e639b1bd45c .1o
c843149c405a3c 10 47c3.co
       |> || |< |  | > |
```

I had some success with using sed capture group but it ignores the trailing spaces.

```
sed -e "s/^.*\(.\)$/\1/"
```

Edit: Clarified that I need space included as well and string includes a dot

Comment: Just a detail, in you comment you put: *I have a list of strings that are always 5 characters long* but in your input **the 5th column is empty at several places**, after the `b <` and the `d <` there should be **2 spaces** right? Is my understanding correct? Could you clarify please?

Comment: @Allan, you're correct

Comment: I have edited the post in order to reflect this constraint! ;-)

Comment: By the way if we answered to your question you can select your favorite answer and set it as "accepted answer" by clicking on the check at the left of it! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using **GNU** awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="";a="";b="";c="";}{a=a$1; b=b$3; c=c$5;}END{print a ORS c ORS b}' filename
```

output:

```
c8431498 0e639b1bd45c 
c843149c405a3c 10 47c3
       |> || |< |< | >
```

Comment: very nice solution, +1 however you can use `FIELDWIDTHS="1 1 1 1 1"` in order to do the same

Comment: "I have a list of strings that are always 5 characters long" so that input need some extra space character end of some row. so output is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one using GNU awk and empty `FS`:

```
$ awk -F "" '{for(i=1;i<=5;i++)a[i]=a[i] ($i==""?" ":$i)}END{print a[1] ORS a[5] ORS a[3]}' file
c8431498 0e639b1bd45c 
c843149c405a3c 10 47c3
       |> || |< |< | >
```

Comment: very nice solution, +1 however you can use `FIELDWIDTHS="1 1 1 1 1"` in order to do the same

Answer (score 4):

Another nice `awk` solution using `FIELDWITHS` awk internal variable:

```
FIELDWIDTHS A  whitespace  separated  list  of field widths.  When set,
            gawk parses the input into fields of fixed  width,  instead
            of  using the value of the FS variable as the field separa-
            tor.  See Fields, above.
```

Example:

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="1 1 1 1 1" '{b1=b1$1;b3=b3$3;b5=b5$5}END{print b1;print b5;print b3}' to_horizontal.txt
c8431498 0e639b1bd45c 
c843149c405a3c 10 47c3
       |> || |< |< | >
```

you can use `FIELDWIDTHS` instead of the classic `FS` in order to defined fixed size columns that will be after manipulated and accessed as usual by using `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ...

Comment: I know but in his explanations: "I have a list of strings that are always 5 characters long", so basically 5th column should not be empty lol

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about using `sed` to solve this, seems very complicated dealing with vertical columns... so, here's a solution using a mash of `cut/paste`

```
$ # paste -s will convert all input lines into single line
$ # \0 delimiter means combine the lines with no character at all in between them
$ cut -c1 ip.txt | paste -sd'\0'
c8431498 0e639b1bd45c .1o
$ cut -c5 ip.txt | paste -sd'\0'
c843149c405a3c 10 47c3.co
$ cut -c3 ip.txt | paste -sd'\0'
       |> || |< |< | > |
```

combining the results:

```
$ (cut -c1 ip.txt | paste -sd'\0'; cut -c5 ip.txt | paste -sd'\0'; cut -c3 ip.txt | paste -sd'\0') > f1
$ cat f1
c8431498 0e639b1bd45c .1o
c843149c405a3c 10 47c3.co
       |> || |< |< | > | 

$ # or use shell looping
$ for i in 1 5 3; do cut -c"$i" ip.txt | paste -sd'\0'; done
c8431498 0e639b1bd45c .1o
c843149c405a3c 10 47c3.co
       |> || |< |< | > |
```

as per [unix.stackexchange - paste files without delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227941/paste-files-without-delimiter), `-d'\0'` is defined by POSIX and should work with any version of `paste`

Comment: Nice pick up for the 5th char empty in his column input data, +1!

Comment: @Sundeep  
  
Can you explain what 's/^...$/& /' does?   
  
I'm using MacOS and BSD paste returns the command usage:
`usage: paste [-s] [-d delimiters] file ...`

Comment: `sed 's/^...$/&  /'` is used here to add two spaces to end of line if there are only 3 characters... because you mention 5 characters every line but given sample input ends with 3 characters only for some lines..

Comment: for paste, may be you need a space after `-d`... does this work? `seq 5 | paste -sd '\0'`

Comment: @Sundeep Apologies, I've updated my post to reflect this and no, I tried that as well as specifying the flags individually with the same result

Comment: @user3534227 in that case, I dunno why it is not working for you... I've updated my answer with modified input and from what I could search online, `-d'\0'` should work for any version of paste

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1s/^(.).(.).(.)$/\1\n\3\n\2/;:a;N;s/(\n.*)(\n.*)\n(.).(.).(.)/\3\1\5\2\4/;ta' file
```

On the first line append newlines after the 1st, 3rd & 5th characters. On all subsequent lines insert the appended lines 1st, 3rd & 5th characters.

N.B. the output requests that the last two lines are swapped therefore the 3rd and the 5th characters are also swapped.